# Does Ubuntu remembers installed softwares in the trial mode from Pen Drive

Tags: 13.04

I have not installed Ubuntu in my computer. I am using it in trail mode (by choosing the option 'Try Ubuntu Without Installing it'. i want to ask that if I install some software on this Ubuntu, will it be there the next time I run it from the pen drive (by choosing again the same option.)

Answer (score 2):

Depends on whether you created a USB drive with **persistence** enabled. If you did, packages and settings will be there the next time you use it.

If you didn't, the official documentation can help you [create a Live Ubuntu with persistence mode](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LiveUsbPendrivePersistent).

Answer (score 0):

When you boot a live CD it loads the OS into memory. As RAM is volitile, none of the changes you make before shutting down the live CD will be kept.